# Hide disabled scrollbar when overflow occurs

Tags: jsp, scroll

When using overflow-x : scroll; and overflow-y: scroll in jsp, if records are more scroll bar is displaying correctly, but when records are less, which means there is no need of displaying any scrollbar, in this case also scrollbar is not coming, this is correct.

But the problem is, scrollbar hidden area is showing like disable one, with top and bottom arrow mark.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add auto like overflow-x:auto and overflow-y:auto